# Hosting website in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I have 2 separate websites on hosted on example.com domain, and other one for french language hosted on fr.example.com.

Now, we need to change the flow of the website languages to be like:
example.com/en
example.com/fr

Is there a method to host the fr.example.com website within a sub folder in example.com?

Regards,
Moayyad

Answer (score 0):

fr.example.com is just a sub-domain of example.com.  That site might already be in a sub folder on the server and just has a "pointer" as the content for the sub-domain.  To do what you want, create a sub directory with the   'fr', 'en', etc, designations and place your websites there.  Each directory would have it's own. index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are try to create a language specific sub domain for you site. You can use host name to achieve this. Try [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: That's what he currently has.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to redirect all requests for example.com/fr/*
to a specific dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/fr/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It will take more then this to setup it properly but you can do your research :)

[htaccess how to](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)